# Using webdrivermanager.properties file with Artifactory

Tags: selenium, webdrivermanager-java

Thank you for the ongoing development/refinement of this project. It is very useful and full-featured ;)  I have been using to run the test locally and it works very well -- as I am trying to move things toward to a pure CI setup; furthermore, looking to take advantage of Docker, and local Artifactory for browser binaries.

In the process of setting things up -- I did notice that the URL's in the webdrivermanager.properties render an XML file when the same is done via Artifactory it's giving me an HTML Index directory page with all version for a given browser binary.

*Error output is as follows:*

```
`[chrome] Operating System: Linux
[chrome] 2018-06-05 13:58:09 WebDriverManager [main] [INFO]Reading https://artifactory.mycompany.com/chromedriver/ to seek chromedriver
[chrome] [Fatal Error] :1:55: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
[chrome] 2018-06-05 13:58:09 WebDriverManager [main] [ERROR]There was an error managing chromedriver 2.25 (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 55; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.)
[chrome] io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 55; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
[chrome]      at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.getDriversFromXml(WebDriverManager.java:797)
[chrome]      at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager.getDrivers(ChromeDriverManager.java:54)
[chrome]      at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.filterCandidateUrls(WebDriverManager.java:492)
[chrome]      at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:442)
[chrome]      at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:219)
[chrome]      at controllers._BrowserFactory.StartBrowser(_BrowserFactory.java:84)
[chrome]      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[chrome]      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[chrome]      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[chrome]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[chrome]      at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
[chrome]      at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
[chrome]      at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
[chrome]      at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
[chrome]      at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
[chrome]      at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
[chrome]      at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
[chrome]      at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
[chrome]      at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
[chrome]      at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
[chrome]      at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
[chrome]      at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
[chrome]      at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
[chrome]      at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
[chrome]      at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
[chrome]      at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
[chrome]      at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
[chrome]      at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
[chrome]      at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
[chrome]      at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
[chrome]      at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[chrome]      at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
[chrome]      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:386)
[chrome]      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:323)
[chrome]      at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:143)
[chrome] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 55; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
[chrome]      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[chrome]      at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
[chrome]      at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.loadXML(WebDriverManager.java:807)
[chrome]      at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.getDriversFromXml(WebDriverManager.java:786)
[chrome]      ... 34 more
`
```

I did come across a similar thread https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/157 but was hoping for any thoughts you may have. Alternative approach on this subject.

Many thanks,
Samir

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still the same you already found on that [issue](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/157). To find out the list of `chromedriver` available binaries, WebDriverManager parses an XML located on some online repository (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ by default).

Therefore, your repository https://artifactory.mycompany.com/chromedriver/ must return an XML with the following format (and not an HTML), which is the one expected by WebDriverManager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01">
    <Name>chromedriver</Name>
    <Prefix />
    <Marker />
    <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
    <Contents>
        <Key>2.0/chromedriver_linux32.zip</Key>
        <Generation>1380149859530000</Generation>
        <MetaGeneration>2</MetaGeneration>
        <LastModified>2013-09-25T22:57:39.349Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>"c0d96102715c4916b872f91f5bf9b12c"</ETag>
        <Size>7262134</Size>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>2.0/chromedriver_linux64.zip</Key>
        <Generation>1380149860664000</Generation>
        <MetaGeneration>2</MetaGeneration>
        <LastModified>2013-09-25T22:57:40.449Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>"858ebaf47e13dce7600191ed59974c09"</ETag>
        <Size>7433593</Size>
    </Contents>

    ...

</ListBucketResult>
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you!